# Named multiprocessing lock

Tags: python

My goal is to lock a directory from multiple processes that will attempt to do git operations on it. **I need to create the lock objects after the processes have branched based on a unique string identifier**. By reading the docs, I have not found any solution in the multiprocessing module.

Here is the code demonstrating the problem:

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process
import os
import time


class NamedResource:

    def __init__(self, identifier: str):
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.lock = Lock()

def work_on(name: str):
    nr = NamedResource(name)
    with nr.lock:
        print(time.time() % 100 // 1, os.getpid(), f"working on {nr.identifier}")
        time.sleep(5)
        print(time.time() % 100 // 1,os.getpid(), f"done with {nr.identifier}")

res = ['a', 'b']
processes = []

for r in res:
    p1 = Process(target=work_on, args=(r,))
    p1.start()

    p2 = Process(target=work_on, args=(r,))
    p2.start()

    processes += [p1, p2]

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

obviously lock objects are different, and they do not prevent the access - as can be seen from the output:

```
67.0 48689 working on b
67.0 48690 working on b
67.0 48688 working on a
67.0 48687 working on a
72.0 48689 done with b
72.0 48690 done with b
72.0 48688 done with a
72.0 48687 done with a
```

correct output would be having only one process work on each of [a, b], but two processes working at a time (because there are two different resources that do not interfere).

In the end I have implemented this using writing a hidden file to the directory I want to limit access to, and checking the presence of this file based on the name in another process. This is not very fast and creates a race condition in the short time between the check and writing the file. Is there a better way?

Comment: What means str from expression identifier:str? Where str is defined? You must complete the code in that sense.

Comment: str is the built-in string type.

Comment: @Mihai8 check out https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/ aka "type hints"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a single `Lock` object can only be entered once. the problem with your code is that you're just creating lots of independent locks, hence processes don't exclude each other as they're all locking/unlocking their own locks

about the nicest way I can get things going is by using a custom `Manager` to expose a single `NamedResource`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

class NamedResource:
    def __init__(self):
        # each client process is served by a seperate thread,
        # this lock is used to serialize access to our state
        self.lock = Lock()
        self.locks = defaultdict(Lock)

    def acquire(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            lock = self.locks[name]
        lock.acquire()

    def release(self, name):
        with self.lock:
            lock = self.locks[name]
        lock.release()

class MyManager(SyncManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('NamedResource', NamedResource)
```

we can change your `work_on` to use this like this:

```
def work_on(name: str, locker: NamedResource):
    locker.acquire(name)
    try:
        print(f"{time.time() % 60:.3f} {os.getpid()} working on {name}")
        time.sleep(0.3)
        print(f"{time.time() % 60:.3f} {os.getpid()} done with {name}")
    finally:
        locker.release(name)
```

you could make a nice context manager to wrap this `acquire` & `release` up if you want

we then put this all together by doing:

```
res = ['a', 'b']
processes = []

with MyManager() as manager:
    locker = manager.NamedResource()

    for r in res:
        p1 = Process(target=work_on, args=(r, locker))
        p1.start()

        p2 = Process(target=work_on, args=(r, locker))
        p2.start()

        processes += [p1, p2]

    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

if you wanted that nice context manager I mentioned above, I'd suggest something like:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseProxy

class NamedResourceProxy(BaseProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('acquire', 'release')

    def acquire(self, name: str):
        return self._callmethod('acquire', (name,))

    def release(self, name: str):
        return self._callmethod('release', (name,))

    @contextmanager
    def use(self, name: str):
        self.acquire(name)
        try:
            yield None
        finally:
            self.release(name)
```

and change the call to `register` to something like: `MyManager.register('NamedResource', NamedResource, NamedResourceProxy)`

you `work_on` could then be something like:

```
def work_on(name: str, locker: NamedResource):
    with locker.use(name):
        print(f"{time.time() % 60:.3f} {os.getpid()} working on {name}")
        time.sleep(0.3)
        print(f"{time.time() % 60:.3f} {os.getpid()} done with {name}")
```

Comment: on python 3.6 and python 3.7 I cant import `from multiprocessing.managers import BaseProxy`

Comment: `BaseProxy` has been there since [Python 2 days](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseProxy), are you sure you're doing what you think you are?

Comment: ok it was only missing from the typeshed .pyi header, so pycharm suggested its missing. Actually the code works.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Do you think it is possible for a process to acquire a valid lock other than getting it as an argument? Can another process connect to a manager by a known port and get the valid lock based on the string? I need to make the API be like in question, for the method 'work_on' to take only the string id.

Comment: multiprocessing allows you to set up a manager as a "server" and connect to it from other processes, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/57077642/1358308 for another post that has code doing this