# Python multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager running registered callable function sequentially

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, blocking

I am working with a remote manager provided by Python's multiprocessing library. I have setup a remote server using BaseManager, to which multiple clients connect simultaneously. Unfortunately, my server is serving requests sequentially for each client. My server is supposed to make a network call to Google's directions API to return distance and time.

My understanding was that a new thread would be spawned for each client that connects, so i would not face this problem.

I have provided a sample of my code in a simplified manner.

Here is the server code:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import threading

class DistanceTime:

    def get_distance_time(self):
        print('started by thread %s'%(threading.get_ident()))
        # assume that network request was made here
        time.sleep(2)
        print('ended by thread %s'%(threading.get_ident()))

def server():
    distance_time=DistanceTime()
    BaseManager.register('get_distance_time', callable=distance_time.get_distance_time)
    manager = BaseManager(address=('localhost', 5000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
    server = manager.get_server()
    print('server running')
    server.serve_forever()

server()
```

Here is the client code:

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time

def client():
    BaseManager.register('get_distance_time')
    manager = BaseManager(address=('localhost', 5000), authkey=b'abracadabra')
    manager.connect()
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    # client mades three simultaneous requests to the server
    b=executor.submit(manager.get_distance_time)
    b=executor.submit(manager.get_distance_time)
    c=executor.submit(manager.get_distance_time)
    print('done')
    time.sleep(5)

client()
```

Even though the client sends all three requests immediately, the server prints the following:

```
server running
started by thread 16740
ended by thread 16740
started by thread 4712
ended by thread 4712
started by thread 7132
ended by thread 7132
```

Ideally, all started prints should come together. This is a major bottleneck for my application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the callable you're `register`ing is a 'creation' method and these are [always run in a locked context](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/multiprocessing/managers.py#L354), but the object it returns is automatically proxied and any methods invoked on it aren't automatically locked

in your demo code, I'd change:

```
def server():
    distance_time=DistanceTime()
    BaseManager.register('get_distance_time', callable=distance_time.get_distance_time)
```

to be:

```
def server():
    distance_time = DistanceTime()
    BaseManager.register('DistanceTime', lambda: distance_time)
```

and then use this as:

```
distance_time = manager.DistanceTime()
a = executor.submit(distance_time.get_distance_time)
b = executor.submit(distance_time.get_distance_time)
c = executor.submit(distance_time.get_distance_time)
```

which should allow everything go in parallel.  I've not actually tested this, but will if you say this doesn't work...

not that it matters here, but I generally feel it's better to register these sorts of things in a separate/derived `Manager`

Comment: Thank you. Your suggestion worked. I can see that the instance of distance time is initiated by the client. This will work good as long as i want to use instance of DistanceTime from one python application. How would i use the same instance from another python application? The ideas was to have a standalone instance of DistanceTime and have other applications use this.

Comment: @shahroze80 I've updated the answer to keep the object as a singleton, is this what you mean?